# Selecting rows based on multiple values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Hello I would like to find out how to select rows (to return data frame) based on multiple values in column for example.  If I have the following data frame:

Name   C1   C2    C3

AAAA   cars    boats    banana

BBBB   red    horse   car

CCCC   white  magic   number

I would like to select the rows in C2 that contain 'boats' and 'magic' and return it is a data frame.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: use `df[df.C2.isin(['boats' ,'magic'])]`

Comment: Thank you.  That worked.